# Any way to set background color of console in python on Mac?

Tags: python, macos, terminal

I want to change the color of the shell window from a running python script on a Mac.

I tried

```
>>> os.system('color 1f')
```

and

```
>>> os.system('setterm -background white -foreground white -store')
```

but neither works.

(I am NOT tring to change background color of pieces of text; I want to change the entire background.)

Regarding all the suggested duplicates, I'm not looking for an AppleScript solution. I need to do this from python, for the current Terminal window that is running the given python process.

Comment: Neither of those commands are installed on my Mac. Do they work for you on the command line?

Comment: No, they do not.

Comment: you can try changing the theme, although I don't know how to do that from terminal.